# Help with computing the Expected Opportunity Loss

Tags: value-of-information

I'm trying to compute the expected opportunity loss (EOL) for a simple investment problem, where the cost ***C*** is set to be exactly 5 million and the value ***V*** is estimated to be normally distributed between 2.5 million and 25 million (with 90% CI).

I understand that the EOL is simply *the cost of making the wrong decision* x *the probability of making the wrong decision*. Here the default decision is to invest. In such case, I assume the EOL can be computed by:

1. chopping the value distribution into small segments
2. for each such segment from the interval (0, *C*] computing its mean and its probability
3. multiplying the mean of each segment by its probability
4. summing up all the products from step 3

Now for this particular case, I computed the EOL to be 246,000. However, this is different from the EOL that was computed for the same problem in the literature that uses a mysterious formula for the computation. I am simply looking for a confirmation that either:

1. the algorithm is wrong
2. the algorithm is correct, but the EOL result is wrong, in which case I need to revise my code
3. both the algorithm and my EOL result are correct, which means that the literature is wrong

Comment: What is the mysterious formula from the literature?

Comment: It's a formula taken from Hubbard's book How to measure anything: EOLF / 1000 * (BB - WB), where EOLF is 15 (based on a EOLF curve and the Relative Threshold factor computed as RT = (C - WB)/(BB - WB)), BB is the Best Bound (25 million) and WB is the worst bound (2.5 million).